# Sitecore custom logs not working on server

Tags: logging, log4net

I'm trying to create a custom log for my application, but for some reason, it is not working when I deployed it into the server. Locally it is working just fine.

I have already tried what's mentioned here but it didn't help:
[Sitecore custom log file is empty](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12706/sitecore-custom-log-file-is-empty)

I have also tried to remove the immediate flush, but that also didn't work. Could someone help me to understand what is going on?

Platform info:

- Sitecore XP version 10.1
- Server is a k8s pod on Azure AKS
- .Net Framework 4.8

My configuration patch file that goes on `{sitecoreXPInstace}/App_Config/Include/MYAPP/Foundation/MYAPP.Foundation.Logging.config`

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
<sitecore>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="MYAPP.Foundation.Logging.Appender"
            type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
            <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/main.{date}.txt" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
            <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
            <immediateFlush value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy/dd/MM} %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
            </layout>
            <encoding value="utf-8" />
        </appender>
        <appender name="IntegrationLogFileAppender"
            type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
            <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/Integration.log.{date}.txt" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
            <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
            <!--<param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />-->
            <ImmediateFlush value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <logger name="MYAPP.Foundation.Logging.SCLogger" additivity="false">
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="MYAPP.Foundation.Logging.Appender" />
            <appender-ref ref="IntegrationLogFileAppender" />
        </logger>
    </log4net>

    <services>
        <register serviceType="MYAPP.Foundation.Logging.SCLogger, MYAPP.Foundation.Logging"
            implementationType="MYAPP.Foundation.Logging.SCLogger, MYAPP.Foundation.Logging"
            resolve="true" scope="Transient" />
    </services>
</sitecore>
```

My Log implementation:

```
using System;
namespace Echopark.Foundation.Logging
{
    public class SCLogger
    {
        private static SCLogger _instance;
        private static readonly object _lock = new object();

        private const string LoggerName = "MYAPP.Foundation.Logging.SCLogger";
        //private static ILog _logger;

        private SCLogger() { }

        public static SCLogger Log
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                        if (_instance == null)
                        {
                            
                            _instance = new SCLogger();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        public void Error(Exception ex, string message, object owner)
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(message, ex, owner);
        }

        public void Warning(string methodName, string message, object owner)
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Warn(message, owner);
        }
    }
}
```

The log file that should not be empty:

[image]

**UPDATE NOTE**

I have tried to update the `<level value="ALL" />` tag to `<priority value="ALL" />` and this also didn't work.

Also, I just saw that I can't delete the log files from the log viewer tool. It says that my log has been used in another process. I have tried to restart the application, but I got the same thing with the difference that I got two logs files with the same name that didn't work.

[image]

**UPDATE NOTE**

I have updated my log to use log4net instead of Sitecore log4net, and it work for a while but after a few logs it have stopped again. It seems that the logs are get truncated.

New log file class:

```
  public class SCLogger
    {
        private static SCLogger _instance;

        private const string LoggerName = "Echopark.Foundation.Logging.SCLogger";
        private static ILog _logger;

        private SCLogger() { }

        public static SCLogger Log
        {
            get
            {
                _instance = new SCLogger();
                _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(LoggerName);

                return _instance;
            }
        }

        public void Error(Exception ex, string message, object owner)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) throw new NullReferenceException(CustomLoggerResource.DefaultEmptyMessageError);

            _logger.Error(message, ex);
        }

        public void Warning(string methodName, string message, object owner)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(methodName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) throw new NullReferenceException(CustomLoggerResource.DefaultEmptyMessageError);

            _logger.Warn(message);
        }
}
```

New config patch:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
        <log4net>
            <appender name="Echopark.Foundation.Logging.IntegrationLogFileAppender"
                type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
                <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/Integration.log.{date}.txt" />
                <appendToFile value="true" />
                <maximumFileSize value="500KB" />
                <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
                <threshold value="5"/>
                <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
                </layout>
            </appender>
            <logger name="Echopark.Foundation.Logging.SCLogger" additivity="false">
                <priority value="ALL" />
                <appender-ref ref="Echopark.Foundation.Logging.IntegrationLogFileAppender" />
            </logger>
        </log4net>
        <services>
            <register serviceType="Echopark.Foundation.Logging.SCLogger, Echopark.Foundation.Logging"
                implementationType="Echopark.Foundation.Logging.SCLogger, Echopark.Foundation.Logging"
                resolve="true" scope="Transient" />
        </services>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: From showconfig.aspx, do you see your configs?

Comment: Yep, it's there.